# Find a plane that passes through a given point and is orthogonal to a given plane

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let $\pi = x+y+z=0$ be a plane. Let $\rho$ be a plane.
The projection of $\rho$ on $\pi$ is a line, and $\rho$ passes through the origin.

Find the plane $\rho$."

What I got:
$\rho$ and $\pi$ are orthogonal because the projection of $\rho$ on $\pi$ is a line. It means that a vector normal to $\pi$ belongs to $\rho$: for example, the vector $(1,1,1)$.

So I have 2 pieces of information about $\rho$: it contains the vector $(1,1,1)$ and the point $(0,0,0)$.

But there are an infinite number of planes that contains a certain vector and passes through a certain point.

So I need another piece of information about $\rho$ to determine it uniquely. For example, another vector it contains.

How do I get that from the question statement?

edit:
Actually it asks for **a** plane, not **the** plane. So, in fact, there are an infinite number of planes that satisfies the statement.

Comment: plan=plane surely

Comment: I don't think $\rho$ is unique. Perhaps a parametric solution is needed?

Comment: My fault. It askes for "a" plane, not "the" plane. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any plane containing $(1,1,1)$ is eligible. For example a plane containing a vector of plane $\pi$ such as $(1,-1,0)$, giving the parametric representation :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&a1+b(1)\\y&=&a1+b(-1)\\z&=&a1+b(0)\end{cases}$$

from which one can deduce the implicit representation

$$2z=x+y$$ by eliminating $a$ and $b$...